# Passing same value to a method and make it return true the first time and false the second time

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Is it possible to pass a value to a method and declare it unique? So that the first time we pass the value it returns true and retains the value and next time it returns false one it checks that it has already been passed once. Is there any code to make it work?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main bb = new Main();

        String a1 = 3000;
        String a2 = 3000;

        boolean output3 = bb.addAccount(a1);
        assertEquals(true, output3);
        
        boolean output4 = bb.addAccount(a2);
        assertEquals(false, output4);
    }

    public boolean addAccount(String acc) {
        int store = 0;
        boolean out = false;
        if (acc == 3000 && store = 0){
            out = true;
            store = 1;
        }
        else if (acc == 300 && store != 0){
            out = false;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: `String a1 = 3000;` nope

Comment: You need to add some data structure to your class that saves all the values already passed to that method. Wether you use an array, a List, a Set or something different is up to you. Then when your method is called check if the passed value already is part of your array/list and if it is return false. Otherwise add it to your list/array and return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// a class field
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();

// a set will return false when adding an existing value
// and return true otherwise. Since sets will not contain
// duplicates adding will not add additional values.
public boolean addAccount(String acc) {
    return seen.add(acc);   
}
```

If this is all you want to do  you don't need a method.  If there is more processing in the method then still use the set, do the processing, and return the appropriate boolean.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. So Hashset allows duplicate values , but not duplicate keys. Thats very useful.

Comment: Not quite.  `HashSet` does not allow duplicates, period.  You're confusing with `HashMap` which allows duplicate values but not duplicate keys.  Also remember set uses a hash to lookup the value so contains is O(1) in efficiency, as opposed to a list which must iterate over the list and is O(n).

Comment: Ok. so thats hashmap...and this is hashset. so neither duplicate keys nor duplicate values. Thank you for explaining. :)

Comment: There are no `values` vs `keys` in hashSet.  It is simply a set of objects.  `Set.of(1,2,3,4)` is a set of 4 integers.